# Send notification every minute from Android app and not every 15 minutes, using PeriodicWork Request by WorkManager

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-workmanager

I want to send notifications from my Android app every minute to the user if a certain condition is met. I read about Periodic Work Request by Work Manager, however the minimum time interval is 15 minutes. How can I set the minimum time to 1 minute instead? The android device is running on Android 9.

Comment: perhaps not relevant, but notifications every minute seems a bit... excessive, does this have to happen if the app is in the background ?

Comment: For the use case of my app, I would need to send in a notification every minute. Yes, it has to happen when the app is in background